# Sequentially solving linear algebra systems in the fastest way

Tags: python, c++, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, gpu

Dear stackoverflow community,

I am currently facing the problem of having to solve a large number of linear algebra systems sequentially, i.e.

solve "Ax = b" with known A (Matrix, 45000 x 45000, ~6 non zeros per row) and b (vector, 45000 rows) for x (vector, 45000 rows).
A is complex symmetric non-Hermitian.

Since there are data dependencies concerning A in each iteration of my algorithm, the linear systems need to be solved sequentially in the least time possible. The vector b is the same for each iteration.

The main code is written in Python 3.7. Using `scipy.sparse.linalg.qmr` I end up at 1.5s per solve.

[MAGMA](https://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/)'s iterative BICGSTAB is able to solve the system within ~0.4s including the overhead of copying the data to the GPU's (RTX 2080) memory. To access the c++ library I use pybind11.

My question now is: Do you have ideas on how to speed up the calculation? I have the feeling that a direct matrix solver rather than an iterative one might be faster. Do you have recommendations for libraries implementing direct solvers which might use the GPU? Is that even possible?

Thank you very much for your help.